# comparing rows in same table

Tags: sql

I am having a result from a query which looks as below

```
+-------------------+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-------------------+
| 1  | x  | y  | z  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | x  | y  | z1 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a  | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c1 |
+-------------------+
```

I need to fetch only records which have values in C1 and c2 different for the same id.

For the above example the result should be

```
+-------------------+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-------------------+
| 2  | a  | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c1 |
+-------------------+
```

Can you please help with the query.

Comment: You say that you're looking for records where the values in C1 and C2 are different, but your example result has c2 the same in both? Could you clarify, please? Other than that, looks like a simple self-join would work fine.

Comment: @MattGibson What I understood from the question, op wants to get results where the combination of `id, c1, c2` is different **between rows**

Comment: Do you need both columns to be different? or either one of them?

Comment: @Lamak Really? Because I'd say we're looking for id to be the same, and not part of the combination. And that would be C1 OR C2 being different, not C1 AND C2 being different. Which is sort of why I was asking for clarification...

Comment: @MattGibson Well, we are kinda saying the same, if `c1 or c2` are different for the same id, then the combination of those 3 columns is different too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joining the table to itself should work. I'm assuming that you meant C1 **or** C2 being different, given the example result you posted.

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.c1,
  t1.c2,
  t1.c3
FROM
  your_table t1 
      INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t1.c1 <> t2.c1 OR
  t1.c2 <> t2.c2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77784/1).

Comment: Yes, it is c1 or C2 . Sorry for not being clear. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you any row which is different of any other. However in the case you have 3 rows, it might not work as you want.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM someTable t1, someTable t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
   AND  (t1.c1 != t2.c1 OR t1.c2 != t2.c2)
```

**Edit:**

If you want only rows that are different of any other row with the same id the first query won't work in this case:

```
+-------------------+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-------------------+
| 1  | x  | y  | z  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | x  | y  | z1 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a  | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c1 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c3 |
+-------------------+
```

You would get:

```
+-------------------+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+-------------------+
| 2  | a  | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c1 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 2  | a1 | b  | c3 |
+-------------------+
```

Which I think would be wrong. In that case you will need something like:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM
(
    SELECT id, c1, c2
    FROM someTable
    GROUP BY id, c1, c2
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t1
JOIN someTable t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
        AND t2.c1 = t1.c1
        AND t2.c2 = t1.c2
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, but I think you need to change the WHERE condition to --> (t1.c1 != t2.c1 OR t1.C2 != t2.C2 ) as the OP wants to check where the individual columns are not matching

Comment: @dubes yyou're right, I had it in mind but then I wrote it wrong. The question says C1 != C2 but the example says what you just said. Tnks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly I think the answer of @MattGibson is correct, but if the order matters then order by clause will be required (order by id).

Comment: Answers don't always appear in the same order, so try to avoid using "above" or "below" in references to other answers. Use the name of the answerer, or the "share" link.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID 
IN(SELECT ID FROM myTable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID)>1)
```